# IE8 doesn't use cookies when it is not the default browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, cookies

I use Google Chrome as my default internet browser, and I'm testing a code I made in HTML which uses cookies to store a variable. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but seems not to save any cookies in IE8, and the IE8 seems to have active the cookies. What can be?

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to create the cookie? And does it indeed work if you make IE the default browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not about what browser is the default? Internet Explorer [requires a domain extension](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/11530.htm) to save cookies, and if you're using `localhost`, it won't save them. Try to make some test domain name like `mytestdomain.local` and set apache up so that it will respond to it.

Then make a hosts file entry that will point `mytestdomain.local` to `127.0.0.1` and it should work.

Comment: no, it doesnt make any diferent

Comment: Then please show how you are trying to use cookies, attach some code to the question.